# Looking for similar strings in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, search

I have a string array. For example:

```
["Tartrazine","Orange GGN", "Riboflavin-5-Phosphate"]
```

And I have a string. For example:

```
"Riboflvin"
```

I want to look for most similar string in the array and get it if it exists.
So I need this output:

```
"Riboflavin-5-Phosphate"
```

But if the array looks like this:

```
["Tartrazine","Orange GGN", "Quinoline"]
```

I want something like this output:

```
"No similar strings found"
```

I tried using [FuzzyWuzzy library](https://github.com/xdrop/fuzzywuzzy), but it shows a lot of false alarms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method, sequentially reducing the length of the string to search if the full string is not found:

```java
String[] arr = {"Tartrazine", "Orange GGN", "Riboflavin-5-Phosphate"};
String element = "Riboflvin";

boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < element.length(); i++) {
    // take shorter substring if nothing found at previous step
    String part = element.substring(0, element.length() - i);
    // if any string from array contains this substring
    if (Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(str -> str.contains(part))) {
        System.out.println("Found part: " + part);
        // then print these strings one by one
        Arrays.stream(arr).filter(str -> str.contains(part))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
// if nothing found
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("No similar strings found");
}
```

Output:

```
Found part: Ribofl
Riboflavin-5-Phosphate
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what you want to do exactly.

There are a couple of things you can do you can check wether the array contains an exact match of the `String` you are looking for by just calling `list.contains("yourStr")` the list directly. You could also check each value to see whether it contains a certain substring like so:

```java
foreach(String s : list) {
    if (s.contains(subStr) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you really would like to check similarity it becomes a bit more complicated. Then we really have to answer the question: "how similar is similar enough?". I guess this post as a decent answer to that problem: [Similarity String Comparison in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955110/similarity-string-comparison-in-java/16018452)